# Monitoring web requests made by a specific javascript src file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm looking for some help with the following:

I'm building a website that links external scripts (these scripts can be changed anytime by the script owner).

I want to route any web requests that's being sent by these scripts through my backend server as a proxy, so that I can parse the request and response to make sure they are not exfiltrating data from my website.

The idea here is to be able to leverage external scripts that cannot be trusted 100% with my data.

---

To enforce this, is it possible to intercept web requests made by `<script>`s from a different `<script>` that loaded early on?

If not, what is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot trust the scripts, this becomes more of a security question. You should get more information about web security in general.

An interesting example of such implementation is [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) and it's permission model (similar to what Android apps).

Depending on the use-case, you may want to manually approve each js file and enforce it via integrity checking:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

At the end of the day, you cannot programmatically check the security of an external js file. You wither trust its author or you don't.